# Is the a function that allows a user to go back in history even if they open a new tab?

Tags: html, browser-history

I have a back button that is suppose to lead me users back to a page in the history. But the issue is that when you right click and open in a new tab when the user clicks on the back button it does not work.

To clarify i have a page with products and there are buttons that go to the checkout page. On that check out page there is a back button using history.back(). but after testing opening the buy button on a new tab makes the back button unusable.

I need a way to prevents this please thank you.

Comment: Look into [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a function for that, but I see two possibilities:

- **document.referrer**  (like ***APAD1*** suggested in the comment section):

  > The referrer property returns the URL of the document that loaded the current document, hence if you do document.referrer, you will only get the URL from the page where you clicked the button to load the current page.
  >   *If you want to be able to not only go to the previous page but also remember the pages loaded before the previous page, then see next option*
- **window.localStorage** and **document.referrer**

  > Since document.referrer only remembers the previous document's URL, you can use window.localStorage to store the history. You can create an array as a localStorage item and add new URLs as you go forward and remove Urls as you go back to a previous page inside the new tab

*More info:*
- [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) 
- [document.referrer](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp) 
- [Window localStorage Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)